# Deployment Status

Tags: deployment, change-set

I have 1 custom object that I deploy via Change Sets. 
Result: Deployment Status page, component count = 1

I deploy same custom object via ANT
Result: Deployment Status page, component count = 17

Here's the kicker... My custom object has:
15 Custom fields
1 CurrencyIsoCode field
1 Owner field
1 Page Layout

No validation rules, field sets, buttons/links etc., no record types, no apex sharing reasons etc..

I presume that Salesforce is counting the custom fields + currencyIsoCode field + object information as distinct components. Has anybody else found this/seen/received an explanation on this from SFDC?

Answer (score 0):

Phil,
It all depends on your package.xml in ANT. If you are individually listing every field (CustomField component), then it will be counted as such. Else, you can just list the entire object (CustomObject) and place all the fields in the associated XML and it will do the same thing (except count as 1).

I have to confess I dont have much experience with ChangeSets but I think you have to add the fields you are interested in moving. Else, the fields are not automatically added in. You can validate this.

Hope this makes sense. Good luck!

Comment: correct -- w/ changesets you have to include each object, each field, each VR manually/individually in the UI otherwise it won't be part of the 'change set'. And you need to remember to include the Profiles otherwise nothing you deploy will be visible (!)